# How to create listener for all signal nodes?

Tags: omnet++

I'm trying to record the latency of the packets in a OMNeT++ network. What I want to store is a tuple < latency, src, dest >. However, this signal would be emitted by a destination node when it receives the complete packet. I suppose that this isn't the best way to do that, because in this way the signal is associated with a specific node, the destination, while this information is "global".

A solution could be to use a listener that registers to the specific signal and gather all the latency coming from all nodes. However, how can I do that without instantiating an additional cSimpleModule (the listener)? Is it possible to have a "static" listener? More in general, is this the best way to do what I have to do?

Comment: You should do exactly what you have written - add an additional simple module which will act as a global listener. And a node which wants to record a tuple will direct call a C++ method defined in this global listener. It may be achieve without using signals at all. Another important issue is: how do you want to write tuples into `OMNeT++` statistics? In `OMNeT++` one can write some *value* into a statistic which has a *name* only, there is no clear possibility to add an *argument* to the statistic. The workaround is to include src and dest address in the name of statistic e.g. "latency-14-6".

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking about always emit 3 signals, one for latency, one for source and one for dest. Maybe it would be clearer to post-process. Suggestions are welcome!

Comment: What exactly do you want to obtain in statistic: *every* latency for the src-dst pair, or only *mean* latency for the scr-dst pair?

Comment: Uhm, on a first moment probably just the mean is ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that node's address is `int` type I suggest the following solution. 
1. Add a new simple module `GlobalListener`:

```
// GlobalListener.ned
simple GlobalListener { }
```

---

```
// GlobalListener.h
#include <omnetpp.h>

using namespace omnetpp;

class NodesPair {
public:
    NodesPair(int _src, int _dst) : src(_src), dst(_dst) {}
    bool operator<(const NodesPair& other) const {
        if (src == other.src)
            return dst < other.dst;
        return src < other.src;
    }
    int src;  // int is an address
    int dst;
};

class Latency {
public:
    Latency() : latencySum(omnetpp::SimTime::ZERO), entries(0) {}
    simtime_t latencySum;
    int entries;
};

typedef std::map<NodesPair, Latency> LatencyTuples;

class GlobalListener: public cSimpleModule {
protected:
    virtual void initialize();
    virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg);
    virtual void finish();
    LatencyTuples latencyTuples;
public:
    void recordLatency(simtime_t latency, int src, int dst);
};
```

---

```
// GlobalListener.cc 
#include "GlobalListener.h"

Define_Module(GlobalListener);

void GlobalListener::initialize() {}

void GlobalListener::handleMessage(cMessage *msg) {}

void GlobalListener::recordLatency(simtime_t latency, int src, int dst) {
    Enter_Method_Silent();

    NodesPair nodes(src, dst);
    if (latencyTuples.find(nodes) == latencyTuples.end()) {
        // new entry for this pair
        Latency latency;
        latencyTuples[nodes] = latency;
    }
    latencyTuples[nodes].latencySum += latency;
    latencyTuples[nodes].entries += 1;
}

void GlobalListener::finish() {
    for (auto it : latencyTuples) {
        int n = it.second.entries;
        simtime_t meanLat = -1; // -1 means: "no latency"
        if (n > 0) {
            meanLat = it.second.latencySum/n;
        }
        char scalar[64];
        sprintf(scalar, "latency-%d-%d", it.first.src, it.first.dst);
        recordScalar(scalar, meanLat);
    }
}
```

2. Place an instance of `GlobalListener` in your NED network and call it `globalListener`.
3. In your `Node.h` add:

   ```
   // forward declaration
   class GlobalListener;
   ```

and inside Node's class:

```
GlobalListener * globalListener;
```

4. In `Node.cc` add:

   ```
   #include "GlobalListener.h"
   ```
5. In `initialize()` in `Node.cc` add:

   ```
   cModule * mod = getModuleByPath("globalListener"); // a name from point 2.
   if (mod) {
       globalListener = dynamic_cast<GlobalListener*>(mod);
   } else {
       error("No globalListener module.");
   }
   ```
6. When you want to record latency in `Node.cc` just call:

   ```
   simtime_t lat = .... ;
   int src = ....;
   int dst = ....;
   globalListener->recordLatency(a, src, dst);
   ```

The statistics will be saved as scalars during finishing simulation.

Comment: What is type of using constructor? in "    NodesPair(int _src, int _dst) : src(_src), dst(_dst) {}" two parameter after colon and expressions src(_src) and dst(_dst)

Comment: It is [C++ initialization list](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html)

Comment: Dear @JerzyD, what is Node.h and Node.cc in the proposed solution? (After stage 3), please explain in more detail.

Comment: It is assumed that simple module called Node was created by questioner and already exists. Node.h and Node.cc define Node class for that module.

Comment: Dear @JerzyD, "It is assumed that a simple module called Node was created by questioner", my question is if that simple module is the AdhocHost node defined in the Inet package, what changes should we make?

Comment: The questioner asked how to create a listener and I presented a way of resolving this issue. Your question "what changes should we make" contains too small amount of information to help you. Moreover, there is a rule in SO that one question resolves one problem. Therefore I suggest creating a new question presenting your current code and the problem you want to resolve.